# Porque no me funciona el sudo apt upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu

Recién acabo de instalar Ubuntu Budgie 21.10, y al querer actualizar los paquetes con `sudo apt update` me ocurre este error:

```
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu impish Release              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho                            
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu impish Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

Estuve checando y al parecer `dawidd0811/neofetch/` dejo de tener actualizaciones hasta Ubuntu 20.04, pero que puedo hacer para dejar de tener ese error y poder instalar otros software que necesito instalar.

Answer (score 3):

Con `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` accedes al archivo de las URL que mira ubuntu al hacer el `sudo apt-get update`

En dicho archivo busca la línea que te esta petando y ponle una almohadilla `#` al inicio de la línea.

De esta manera la comentaras vuelve a lanzar el comando de `sudo apt-get update` y ya no te saltara el error porque no mirara ese repositorio.

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en la respuesta de @JordiTurrel. Puedes intentar automatizar la respuesta con un comando con `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's@(^<dirección problemática>@#\1@g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

O sea:

```
$ sudo sed -r 's@(^http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu)@#\1@g'
```

Si te gustó como se vió la salida, entonces añade el parámetro `-i` al comando de `sed`, para editar el archivo.